# Spliting string without spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find a way to split each letter in a word to a list.

I have tried to do this with a for letter in message add space but this hasn't worked.

```
message = 'hello'

for letter in message:
  letter += ' '

message = message.split()

print(message)
```

I get

```
['hello']
```

I want

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Comment: Have you tried `list(message)`? :)

Comment: The reason `letter += ' '` doesn't do anything is because you're modifying `letter` with it, but not `message`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is an *iterable*. When iterating over a string, it yields each character individually. The `list()` constructor takes an iterable and creates a list out of its individual elements. So:

```
message = 'hello'
message = list(message)
print(message)
# ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 2):

A string is already an array of charecters. Use `list(str)`

Example:

```
message = 'hello'
char_array = list(message)
print char_array
```